# Decision Trees split in scikit

Tags: scikit-learn, decision-trees

I am working with the titanic dataset and using decision trees for analyzing the age covariate. I'd like just to see whether kids are more likely to survive than adults. I implemented my own Gini coefficient and I had plot the coefficient by age: dataset here [titanic ds](https://github.com/juan-barragan/titanic/blob/master/titanic_ds.csv)

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import tree
import graphviz
import numpy as np

def gini_by_age(df, t):
    df['age_group'] = df['age'].apply(lambda row : 0 if row <= t else 1)
    kids = df[df['age_group'] == 0]
    kids0 = kids[kids['survived'] == 0]
    kids1 = kids[kids['survived'] == 1]
    adults = df[df['age_group'] == 1]
    adults0 = adults[adults['survived'] == 0]
    adults1 = adults[adults['survived'] == 1] 
    gk = 1 - (len(kids0)**2 + len(kids1)**2)/float(len(kids))**2
    ga = 1 - (len(adults0)**2 + len(adults1)**2)/float(len(adults))**2

    return gk + ga

def plot_gini_by_age(df):    
    ages = range(2,25)
    y = [gini_by_age(df, a) for a in ages]
    plt.plot(ages, y)
    plt.show()

def use_tree(df):
    X = np.array(df['age']).reshape((len(df['age']),1))
    y = df['survived']
    clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=1).fit(X,y)    
    dot_data = tree.export_graphviz(clf, out_file=None)
    graph = graphviz.Source(dot_data)
    graph.render("age")

titanic_df = pd.read_csv("titanic_ds.csv")
ages_cov = titanic_df[['age', 'survived']].dropna()
plot_gini_by_age(ages_cov)
use_tree(ages_cov)
print gini_by_age(ages_cov, 5)
print gini_by_age(ages_cov, 8.5)
print gini_by_age(ages_cov, 15)
```

output:
    0.925844132419
    0.937732003001
    0.963875889772
I see from the plot that gini coefficient has local minima at roughly 5, 8 and 15 years old and the best is at 5. But scikit gives me 8.5 years old as the best split. What is wrong here?

Comment: If you want to Visualize what's your tree doing, use `graphviz`

Comment: I used graphviz as you can see on the function use_tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it thanks to the scikit team, I put the answer here for the people to come. The split used in scikit uses weights in calculating the Gini coefficient, just add the following lines before returning:
    ....
    gk *= len(kids)/len(df)
    ga *= len(adults)/len(df)